# Email marketing tracking on GA for FB ads

Tags: google-analytics

I used a URL builder to create and define parameters based on ad and the ad set for facebook but when I am trying to track the performance in GA, it doesn't return anything.

Any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related.

Comment: Where would you suggest I post this. I added the right tag

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ will help you understand why things are not working in the Google analytics web application.  SO is for programming related questions you dont appear to have any code in your question.  IF you do have a coding issue please feel free to post your code and we will have a look at it.